# Inline conversion/cast from Expression<Func<T, int>> to LambdaExpression

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code (I need the `LambdaExpression` as not all `Func<>`'s are `T, int`):

```
var orderDelegates = new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>();

Expression<Func<Image, int>> id = i => i.Id;
orderDelegates.Add(ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ID, id);
```

Is it possible to make this shorter?

Best something like:

```
var orderDelegates = new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>()
{
    { ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ID, ????? },
    ...
};
```

I already tried the following, which did not work:

```
orderDelegates.Add(ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ID, (Expression<Func<Image, int>>)i => i.id);
//or
orderDelegates.Add(ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ID, i => i.id as Expression<Func<Image, int>>);
```

I "improved" it a little to the following already, but "full inlining" would be the desired result:

```
public static Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression> GetOrderDelegates<T>() where T : ContentItem
{
    Expression<Func<T, int>> id = i => i.Id;
    Expression<Func<T, bool>> enabled = i => i.IsEnabled;
    Expression<Func<T, IComparable>> author = i => i.Creator.UserName;
    //...

    return new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>()
        {
            { ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ID, id },
            { ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ENABLED, enabled },
            { ContentItem.ORDER_BY_AUTHOR, author },
            //...
        };
}
```

Comment: So, what do you know about the lambdas, are they all `Func<Image, something>` or at least `Func<something1, something2>`?

Comment: @svick: Yes, they are all `Func<T, something>`...

Comment: whats `ContentItem`?

Comment: @Nik: `ContentItem` is my base class, which holds all common properties like `Id` and all my (content-)items use classes derived from it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by creating a custom class that supports collection initializers. Its `Add()` method would be generic, so that it fits any allowed expression:

```
class ExpressionDictionary<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, LambdaExpression>>
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression> m_dictionary
        = new Dictionary<string, LambdaExpression>();

    public void Add<TResult>(string key, Expression<Func<T, TResult>> expression)
    {
        m_dictionary.Add(key, expression);
    }

    public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<string, LambdaExpression>> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return m_dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
new ExpressionDictionary<T>
{
    { ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ID, i => i.Id },
    { ContentItem.ORDER_BY_ENABLED, i => i.IsEnabled },
    //the cast is necessary if the result has to be Func<T, IComparable>
    // and not Func<T, string>
    { ContentItem.ORDER_BY_AUTHOR, i => (IComparable)i.Creator.UserName },
    //...
};
```

You will need to add other methods to `ExpressionDictionary`. Either implement the whole `IDictionary<TKey, TValue>` interface and make `GetOrderDelegates()` return that. Or just add a getter for the private `Dictionary` and return that.

But even better option might be not to use Dictionary at all. Instead create `OrderByDeletegates` class (though that's probably not the best name, since it would contain expressions, not delegates) that would have properties for all expressions:

```
class OrderByDeletegates<T> where T : ContentItem
{
    public Expression<Func<T, int>> OrderById { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, bool>> OrderByEnabled { get; set; }
    public Expression<Func<T, IComparable>> OrderByAuthor { get; set; }
    // …
}
```

Usage:

```
new OrderByDeletegates<T>
{
    OrderById = i => i.Id,
    OrderByEnabled = i => i.IsEnabled,
    OrderByAuthor = i => i.Creator.UserName,
    // …
};
```

The advantage of this is that it's type-safe. You can't for example accidentally do something like `OrderByEnabled = i => i.Id`.

Comment: This are great ideas, but the second one will not work in my case, as I use the `string`-key of the dictionary to select the correct delegate/expression...
I try implementing your first idea as an extension to my dictionary and report back.

Comment: @chrfin Why do you need to use the key? Can't you just access the properties directly?

Comment: Because the key comes in as a string from the (Web-)Front-End (e.g "mydomain.com/page?sortKey=Author" will sort after the expression with the key "Author")...

Comment: Went with your first solution and works fine...

Comment: note that `Expression<Func<T, TResult>>` does not guarantee that TResult is a member of T which I think was the op intent